# How to figure out the ration between various values folder in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-screen-support

I have just started working on `supporting multiple screen` section in android but unfortunately I got late and defined three of my layout respective to `xxhdpi` devices. Now, I created following folders for applying various dimensions:

- values
- values-hdpi
- values-xhdpi
- values-xxhdpi

and copy my `dimens.xml` in all of them. The reference I choose to create `layout` was `xxhdpi` (Nexus 5). Now how to figure out the ratio? So that I can change my `dimens.xml` in `values`, `values-hdpi` , `values-xhdpi` and for `Nexus 6` device?

For instance here is my one `dimen` instance in `xxhdpi`:

```
<dimen name="move_in_margin_top">250dp</dimen>
```

I know this is stupid but I don't have any other option right now.

Answer (score 0):

1.0x baseline for medium-density,
1.5x for high-density,
2.0x for extra-high-density,
3.0x for extra-extra-high-density,
4.0x for extra-extra-extra-high-density

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `dp` - is density independent unit, so **you don't have to copy `dimen.xml` to every folder - just leave it in the `values`**. (In other words, if you want to have **the same** physical size - leave other `values-...` folders empty).
 Only .png files due to their nature should be supplied for every dimension
**Edit**
If you want to center an item - use android:gravity="center" (android:layout_gravity="center") but not the margin/padding. Margin/padding may differ a little

**2)** Anyway, if you want to know ratio here it is (it may be useful when dealing with .png):
mdpi  = 1
hdpi  = 1.5
xhdpi = 2
xxhdpi= 3

Comment: So you are saying that I should have to leave `dimens.xml` in values folder but what would other folders (hdpi, xhdpi and etc) will have?

Comment: If you want to have the same physical size - leave them empty. Only .png files due to their nature should be supplied for every dimension

Comment: I do have different size images for every resolution. Sorry I am not getting you. You are asking me to leave them as a blank folders. My size is defined in `dp` (Margin) and sp for width but still it got some distortion (minor distortion) from nexus 5 to nexus 6 to nexus one. How can I handle it?

Comment: Yes, images should be supplied for every density. But values - shouldn't. Minor distortions, as I understand you, are because you have only density-classes (like mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc). And inside one class you may have minor differences between particular devices just because their actual densities differ a little

Comment: So, everything is right here then? Let's say I put a button Horizontal center in xxhdpi device but it's not showing in center in xxxhdpi device (slightly left)

Comment: If you want to center an item - use android:gravity="center" (android:layout_gravity="center_vertical") but not the margin/padding.
Margin/padding may differ a little